# Query Mongo DB using Java Driver

Tags: java, regex, mongodb

So I have a list of `queryObjects` (a class I created in my program) to query from a mongo DB with expressions all in an object like (pseudo code):

```
queryObject : { fild, operation, expression }
```

example : `queryObject : { field : "pagePath", operation:"$in", expression:"/home"}`

And the user can create as many queries as he/she wants. This works like charm until I have two queries with the same field name, example:

`queryObject1 : { field : "pagePath", operation:"$in", expression:"/home"}`

`queryObject2 : { field : "pagePath", operation:"$regex", expression:"(.html)$"}`

than I have: query.put(queryObject1) and query.put(queryObject2)
this command:

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable = statistics.find(query).projection(excludeId());
```

takes into consideration only the second put, what made me think that maybe it overrides the first. What can I do to prevent this from happening? is there a query syntaxe in Mongo that allows me to test that the Page Path is both a Home Page and ends with .html? knowing that this condition can change I always have to read the Query Object and create a MongoQuery in my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your query object basically generates a Bson which can be used for Collection.find(), you can combine multiple Bsons via the Filters-utilities:

```
Bson b1 = firstQuery.convertToDbQuery(); // or however you do it... ;-)
Bson b2 = secondQuery.convertToDbQuery();
Bson combinedAsAnd = Filters.and(b1, b2);
collection.find(combinedAsAnd).projection(...)
```